# MDX Formula with Excel OLAP-Extension

Tags: excel, pivot, mdx, olap

I am not able to figure this out:

Lets say i got an olap-table wihich displays some facts about a product. One of those is the volume of its sales.

How can I add a Field which displays me the Difference to the last year? Provided that I am not allowed to create a new measure, but using a formula?

[image]

Something "easy" like my pseudocode:

```
[Measures].[Volume] From 'FilterYear'
- [Measures].[Volume] From 'FilterYear' -1
```

Is that even possible? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is totally possible but requires a little bit more MDX trickery than your pseudocode.

Try something like:

```
Aggregate([Date].CurrentMember.Lag(1), [Measures].[Volume])
```

This assumes you're using a year member in some axis; if you selected a day member instead, it would give you volume for the previous day instead.

[Here's a good resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145524.aspx) about the Aggregate function and MDX functions in general.

Comment: Thank you very much. We found a different soloution now but I keep in mind what you wrote for the future.